# Nomenclature of aldehydes with double bonds and stereoisomerism

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I'm struggling to name this compound shown below:

[image: structural formula of compound]

I'll post my chain of thought here so it can be corrected!

- longest chain is marked as below:

[image: structural formula of compound with potential longest carbon chain marked]

- this is because the functional group with the highest priority is the aldehyde (HCO) functional group, so the chain should contain this functional group
- the chain continues down to to bottom-right to obtain the maximum length with the greatest number of substituents (although actually looking at it now, could the carbon chain go left and skip the double bond?)
- there's a butyl side chain on carbon 3
- there's a double bond at carbon 3
- there's an ethyl side chain on carbon 4
- there are two methyl groups on carbon 5
- following CIP rules, the groups with highest priority are arranged opposite each other, so the molecule is E

Therefore, would the molecule be (*E*)-3-butyl-4-ethyl-5,5-dimethylhex-3-enal?
Or have I got myself completely mixed up...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Kipf: What you have suggested is reasonable but apparently not the latest version of the rules. (E)-3-(2,2-dimethylpentan-3-ylidene)heptanal.

Comment: That’s not the longest chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IUPAC has changed some of the rules of nomenclature as of 2013. In aldehyde **1** both the aldehyde group and double bond are included in the base name (noun) and the methyl group is the substituent (adjective) because both chains are $\ce{C4}$. In structure **2** the methyl group of **1** has been changed to ethyl. Now the longest chain is $\ce{C5}$ containing the aldehyde group and the double bond, as a substituent is the modifier methylene. In structure **3** the branch at $\ce{C3}$ has two $\ce{C3}$ units. The one containing the double bond takes priority as the "noun". In structure **4** the chain containing the double bond is shorter, which becomes the "adjective". In your compound **5**, the noun is heptanal (in black) and the adjective, which contains the double bond, is in red. The two entities are numbered independently.

[image]